# Cloning a hard drive and using it to boot on a different system

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, clone

Can I clone a hard drive and use it to boot on a different system? Windows XP, from Intel to AMD.

I used HDclone and copied my HD. When I tried to boot up with the new hard drive in the AMD system, Windows begins to load then blue screens and resets. I changed boot priorities and whatnot in the BIOS. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Changing the entire computer, except the boot disk, will require the re-activation of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Try a repair installation of windows xp by booting off a windows xp cdrom. After copying the installation data to the drive, you should boot once again from the cdrom - not from your harddrive - to finish the installation.

Go ahead as described [here](http://www.cpuhack.com/wordpress/?p=142).

Answer (score 1):

What you did wrong was expect XP to load drivers from different hardware and think it would boot properly.

Paragon makes some cloning software that will strip out all the old drivers and allow it to boot on new hardware. Then you can install the new motherboard drivers.

See scenario #3 on this page

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/dc-personal/

.